# How do I use python to download an S3 file from a link with a signature and expiration?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, download, urllib, boto3

I have a s3 link provided to me by a third-party with the following structure: `http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name_possibly/path/to/file_possibly/filename?AWSAccessKeyId=SomeKey&Expires=888888&Signature=SomeCharactersPossiblyHTMLencoded`

Clicking on the link downloads the file for me. However, in python when I try to use `urllib.request.urlretrieve(link_string)` on the link I get the error `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`

I have also tried using boto3 and manually parsing out the bucket_name, key, AWSAccessKeyID as well as the signature(treating it as the AWSSecretAccessKey - I know that this is probably wrong). I setup a client with the credentials and try to run a get_object method. Something similar to below:

```
client= boto3.client(
  's3',
  aws_access_key_id='AWSACCESSKEY',
  aws_secret_access_key='SomeCharactersPossiblyHTMLencoded',
  config=Config(signature_version='s3v4') # tried with/without this option
)
client.get_object(
   Bucket='bucket_name_possibly',
   Key='path/to/file_possibly/filename'
 )
```

The resulting error is `An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the GetObject operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method`.

I am stuck, how can I get python to programmatically download the link?

Answer (score 0):

You can use boto to download file as follows.

```
import boto3
import botocore

BUCKET_NAME = 'my-bucket' # replace with your bucket name
KEY = 'my_image_in_s3.jpg' # replace with your object key

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

try:
    s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(KEY, 'my_local_image.jpg')
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
        print("The object does not exist.")
    else:
        raise
```

for more info you can refer [this](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html)

Comment: Unfortunately the bucket is not mine. I do not want to use my own credentials for this file download. How should I extract the credentials from the url?